# Invalid ColumnName, but ColumnName is correct (EFC)

Tags: entity-framework-core

So i'm trying to learn Design First EFC, but I have a problem getting Entities to work that have a many relationship with another Entity. I get this error message:SqlException: Invalid column name 'GuestListId'.

For experimentation I changed to the table into a one relationship. That works perfectly

This works:

```
 public class GuestList
    {
        public Guid GuestListId { get; set; }
        public Guest? Guest { get; set; }
    }
```

However, when I want to have a many relationship, it does not work and fires the following errorcode:  SqlException: Invalid column name 'GuestListId'.

This somehow does not work:

```
 public class GuestList
    {
        public Guid GuestListId { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Guest>? Guest { get; set; }
    }
```

So I checked the GuestList table in SSMS, but that is identical to the entity in the sourcecode.  I also updated the table but I still get the same problem. Does anyone have an idea what the problem is?

EDIT: So after a suggestion by someone, I added a GuestList property in Guest. But that still gives the same error:

```
  public class Guest
    {
        public Guid GuestId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public GuestList GuestList { get; set; }
    }
```

So this is a picture of the sourcecode I have now that tries to insert data into the database.
[Sourcecode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVHPk.png)
When I check the database, is see that GuestId value is not being assigned in the GuestList. But in the guest table I see that the GuestListid is being assigned:

[Database Guest Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7E1J.png)
[Database GuestList Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLtgs.png)

EDIT: I got it working now. As suggested, I migrated and updated my database. some tables have changed now. GuestList has only one column now and Guest has an extra column called GuestListId.  See the pictures below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06MFF.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFI4R.png)

Comment: When you change the relationship to be `many`, then a FK column named 'GuestListId' is expected in the *dependent* (related) table/entity (`Guest` probably).

Comment: I tryed what you did, but it still does not work. Do I have to add a extra column in the database for the GuestTable with a foreign key to GuestList?

Comment: Of course you have to - the C# and database models should match. Generate EF Core migration and you'll see. With relational database you can't just change objects and not update the relational structure, because relational databases implement relationships with FKs rather than containment.

Comment: As for your "try", it wasn't necessary to add navigation property in 'Guest` class - having a collection navigation property in `GuesList` already considers (and expects) a FK column/relationship in `GuestTable`. That's why you getting the original error. And the fix is not to add properties to the `Guest` object, but update the database with the new structure implied from the code changes (design/code first flow).

Comment: That is also the problem I update my database everytime after a change in the source code, but it error keeps returning.

Comment: To be clear, update means first issuing "add migration", then "update database" commands. Is that what you are doing? I doubt, because the `Guest` table shown on the picture is not correct for this model (should not have `GuestId` column). And you haven't shown the `Guest` table which should be source of the problem, so we cannot verify if it is correct or not. If you want a concrete answer, include in the question **both** entity classes, fluent configuration if any, and the code line which generates the error.

Comment: I think it's working now. I added a migration and then updated it. I noticed that the table GuestList has completly changed. It now only has one column called GuestListId and the table Guest has a extra column now with GuestListId. It works like a charm now. I guess this is how EFC works? I would have prefered to have the GuestList table to know about all the Guest and that the guest table doesn't know anything about GuestList.

Comment: EFC is just the intermediator. This is how *relational* databases work. EFC is ORM (**O**bject **R**elational **M**apper), hense just translates(**m**aps) your **o**bject model to **r**elational database tables. If you have to do it manually (without EFC), you have to do exactly the same.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and help. You really helped me out and I learned a lot from this. Thank you!